# How can I get the mailbox email details from Exchange Server for a user which don't have default mailbox (I have no default mailbox)?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

Hi I want to access the email of mailbox which is assign to me but it is not my primary mailbox in my Exchange Server.

I was able to get details of the mailbox server which is assigned to me, but I have a user which doesn't have a mailbox.

I want to know how to access that.

I read something related to Impersonation or delegation.

This is not working as the new user doesn't have primary mail.

> - How can I get how many mailbox assign to the user?
> - How can I get particular mailbox email for a user?

I was able to access my mailbox, but when I am trying to access the mailbox for user which doesn't have primary mailbox to it, I am not able to get.

```
 ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user-name", "password", "domain");
        //Autodiscover end point
        service.Url = new System.Uri("https://exchange-url/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
        FolderId SharedMailbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "maibox-name");
        ItemView itemView = new ItemView(1000);
        service.FindItems(SharedMailbox, itemView);
```

What can i do?

Comment: Exchange Administrator should delegate an access to you.

Comment: Whats the error? Your code is exactly how it should be, so programmatically we cant help you. Can you verify @SergeyVaulin comment - you do have permission?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found an interesting solution to this issue using Independentsoft.Exchange. Link [here](http://www.independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/index.html). and below is the code

```
 NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
 Service service = new Service("https://exchange-url/EWS/Exchange.asmx", credential);
 Independentsoft.Exchange.Mailbox mailbox = new Independentsoft.Exchange.Mailbox("MysecondEmail@mydomain.com");
 StandardFolderId InboxFolder = new StandardFolderId(StandardFolder.Inbox, mailbox);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: will check this .